# Is this variable transformation correct? (Question Rephrased)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Define for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ the following function :
$$
f(t):=
\begin{cases}
t+1&\text{if $-1\leq t<0$}\\
1&\text{if $0\leq t<1$} \\
2&\text{if $1\leq t<2$}\\
t-3&\text{if $2\leq t\leq 3$}
\end{cases}
$$
I wish to determine $f\left(-\frac{t}{2}+4\right)$. Is my derivation correct?
\begin{align*}
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
t+1&\text{if $-1\leq t<0$}\\
1&\text{if $0\leq t<1$} \\
2&\text{if $1\leq t<2$}\\
t-3&\text{if $2\leq t\leq 3$}
\end{cases}
&\iff
\overbrace{\begin{cases}
-\frac{t}{2}+1&\text{if $-1\leq -\frac{t}{2} <0$}\\
1&\text{if $0\leq -\frac{t}{2}<1$}\\
2&\text{if $1\leq-\frac{t}{2}<2$} \\
-\frac{t}{2}-3&\text{if $2\leq t\leq 3$}
\end{cases}}^{t\implies-0.5t}
\\ \\
&\iff
\overbrace{\begin{cases}
-\frac{(t+4)}{2}+1&\text{if $-1\leq-\frac{t}{2}+4<0$}\\
1&\text{if $0\leq-\frac{t}{2}+4<1$} \\
2&\text{if $1\leq-\frac{t}{2}+4<2$}\\
-\frac{(t+8)}{2}-3&\text{if $2\leq-\frac{t}{2}+4\leq 3$}
\end{cases}}^{-0.5t\implies -0.5t+4}\\ \\
&\quad\;=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{t}{2}+1&\text{if $-1\leq-\frac{t}{2}+4<0$}\\
1&\text{if $0\leq-\frac{t}{2}+4<1$} \\
2&\text{if $1\leq-\frac{t}{2}+4<2$}\\
-\frac{t}{2}-7&\text{if $2\leq-\frac{t}{2}+4\leq 3$}
\end{cases}\\ \\
&\iff
\begin{cases}
-\frac{t}{2}+1&\text{if $8\leq t<10$}\\
1&\text{if $6\leq t<8$} \\
2&\text{if $4\leq t< 6$}\\
-\frac{t}{2}-7&\text{if $2\leq t\leq 4$}
\end{cases} \\ \\
&\quad\;=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{t}{2}-7&\text{if $2\leq t\leq 4$}\\
2&\text{if $4\leq t< 6$}\\
1&\text{if $6\leq t<8$} \\
-\frac{t}{2}+1&\text{if $8\leq t<10$}
\end{cases} \\
\end{align*}

> $(1)$: Is my derivation correct?

> $(2)$: If yes, is there any alternative faster method?

Comment: anyone?......... :(

Comment: No. When you broke your substitution into two steps, you severely garbled the second step. You would have been much wiser to substitute $\left(-\frac t2 + 4\right)$ for $t$ everywhere at the very start. It looks like you handled the inequalities for each piece well, but the function values in the two non-constant pieces is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!